# Just as X was ..., it will be

Tags: comparative-constructions

"Just as my money was the first in, it will be the last out." - Elon Musk. Can someone explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is reassuring his investors and creditors that he will not withdraw his own money from Tesla by selling his stock: his money was the first invested in the company, and it will be the last to be taken out by disinvestment.